# Redirect url with .htaccess is adding old path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, codeigniter-3

In the same domain, I want to make a 301 redirect from `/this/old/path/file.pdf` to `/this/new/path#abc`

I tried this:

`Redirect 301 /this/old/path/file.pdf /this/new/path#abc`

And it does the redirect but showing the following path:

`/this/new/path#abc?/this/old/path/file.pdf`

It should be:

`/this/new/path#abc`

Any hint of what is wrong here?

---Update
This is the content of my .htaccess file usign just redirect

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    Redirect 301 /this/old/path/file.pdf /this/new/path#abc
</IfModule>
```

And usign RewriteRule

```
RewriteOptions inherit
Options FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule /this/old/path/file.pdf /this/new/path#abc [NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This doesn't make any redirect

Don't know if this is important but I am using CPanel.

Comment: Use `RewriteRule` instead of `Redirect` with an `NE` flag

Comment: That rule alone wouldn't result in the response you are seeing. What other directives do you have?

Comment: I have updated my question trying with @anubhava approach.

Comment: @MrWhite what do you mean with directives?

Comment: "Directives" are the commands you are using. ie. `Redirect`, `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` are all "directives".

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. Answering your question, I am not using any other directive.

Comment: `RewriteOptions inherit` - do you know what directives you are inheriting?

Comment: Are you serving multiple domains using this config? Otherwise, there is no need to check the `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: I don't know what other directives I am inheriting and yes, I am serving multiple domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` (mod_alias) directive is applied after the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directives, so you are seeing the query string that is applied by the earlier `RewriteRule` internal rewrite. You basically have a conflict between mod_alias and mod_rewrite.

You need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive instead *before* your existing rules, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive. Not at the end. The order is important.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^this/old/path/file\.pdf$ /this/new/path#abc [NE,R=301,L]
```

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. The first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (the *pattern*) is a regex, so the necessary escaping and anchors need to be applied.

The *condition* that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable is necessary if you need this rule to apply only to the stated domain.

The `NE` flag is required to prevent the `#` character being URL-encoded in the response (negating its meaning a fragment identifier delimiter).

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. And test first with 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thanks for this, the problem was the order of the directives. Now the redirect is working perfectly.

Comment: @CarlosSivira Glad this resolved the issue. The problem was not _only_ the order of the directives. The `RewriteRule` directive you had would never have matched, regardless of where the rule was used.

Comment: Your are right!